# IF function testing multiple arguments

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have three columns with **Results**, **Deviation**, and **Amount out of Tolerance**.

```
Results  |  Deviation  |  Amount out of Tolerance
```

The **Results** column can contain numbers for measured results, but it can also contain a yes or no answer.

The **Deviation** `IF` statement that I have right now is: 

`=IF(ISBLANK(J14)," ",IF(ISERR(J14-D14),"---",J14-D14))`

The **Amount out of Tolerance** `IF` statement is:

`=IF(ISBLANK(J14),"",IF(J14>=G14,(J14-G14),IF(J14<=H14,(H14-J14),"")))`

This gives an outcome that gives the difference of how much out of spec the result might be. Some of the requirements however aren't numerical values, instead it may be making sure dimensions are in accordance or that the digital files contain fillets, etc.

Because of this, at times I want the **Results** to be a yes or no answer, but I want the **Deviation** and **Amount out of Tolerance** to show no values because with those `IF` statements, it gives a `#VALUE!` answer (which looks bad).

---

#### To sum it up:

I need to be able to have **Results** be a "yes" or "no" answer, and if it's one of those rather than a numerical value, the outcome in **Deviation** and **Amount out of Tolerance** columns should be blank.

I tried to change it to this:

 
`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(J14),"",IF(ISERR(J14-D14), "--",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes", J14)), ""))))`

I was hoping this would see if there's a yes answer, and if so, then it would be kept blank, but it didn't work. I'm not sure what else to do. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ISNUMBER` function. Note that blanks are not numbers so you won't have to also use `ISBLANK`.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(J14), J14-D14, ""))`

**Edit**:

To be more robust you probably want to test every cell in the equation (the subtraction in your case):

`=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(J14), ISNUMBER(D14)), J14-D14, ""))`

Comment: Andrew, when I use this equation for the Deviation column and I input a "yes" or "no" answer in the Results column, I obtain a blank value (which is good.) However, When I put in a numerical value such as 5, the deviation should output a value of 5, but in this case it still contains a blank value. Any recommendations?

Comment: Both `J14` and `D14` must be numbers for the formula to show the subtraction result. Assuming `J14` is "Results" and contains a number, what is in `D14`?